# Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value while loading webView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My swift program is crashing while I'm trying to load webView inside
 ***prepare for segue*** 
I don't know why the webView = ***nil***

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    var booksController = segue.destination as! PDFDisplayVC

    if navigationItem.title == "Math" {
        let mathBookURL = URLRequest(url: booksController.mathBook!)
        booksController.webView.load(mathBookURL) // <- Crash


    }
}
```

Here's the code in the PDFDisplayVC

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
class PDFDisplayVC : UIViewController {

//OUTLET
@IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

/*--------URL REQUEST--------*/
let mathBook = URL(string: "https://drive....")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If explained in more detail than Andrei's answer, in `booksController.webView.load(mathBookURL)` your `webView` is not initialized yet, that's why it's `nil`.

What Andrei is suggesting is, instead of calling `load` method of `UIWebView` directly in `prepareForSegue` method, you can have a variable called `mathBookURL` (like `var mathBookURL: URL?`) in your `PDFDisplayVC`, and in `viewDidLoad` of `PDFDisplayVC` you can call `webView.load(mathBookURL!)`. In that case you have to assign the right url to the `mathBookURL` variable in `prepareForSegue` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Fahri , but i added the `var mathBookURL: URLRequest?` in the **_PDFDisplayVC_**  and `webView.load(mathBookURL!)` to the viewDidLoad of the **_PDFDisplayVC_** also I wrote `booksController.mathBookURL = URLRequest(url: booksController.mathBook!)` in perpareForSegue but XCode still show me the same error at `webView.load(mathBookURL!) // <- CRASH`

Comment: Then, you have to make sure that your `webView` is connected to the `IBOutlet` in storyboard. You can also debug your app in the place of crash to see exactly what's `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `webView.load(mathBookURL)` during or after `viewDidLoad`.